# Maven repository set up not working in azure devops

Tags: azure, maven, intellij-idea, azure-devops, mvn-repo

I am setting up maven repository in azure devops. With the new feed, I was able to publish artifacts. On the other side I was able to download packages and my client program compiles but it does not run with the following error

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl;
at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:458)

The artifact which was downloaded on client side is dependent on okhttp3 but somehow it is not finding it. I already see okhttp3 in this folder:repository\com\squareup but the code does not find it

On publishing side, we are already publishing uber jars and it should have all the dependencies

here is pom.xml change

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>msazure-visualstudio-com-msazure-id</id> 
<url>https://msazure.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/id/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>msazure-visualstudio-com-msazure-id</id>
<url>https://msazure.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/id/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

How can I make this thing work?